# RequireJS: how to control the execution sequence of the paralleled loaded js script

Tags: javascript, requirejs

i have no doubts on the parallel scripts loading step, but i would like to know how RequireJS control the execution sequence of the parallel loaded scripts.

example defined as below.

```
<script data-main="js/main.js" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

main.js:

```
define(['a', 'b'], function() {
    window.alert("scheduler loaded!");
})
```

how to ensure that a.js is executed before b.js?
and when the main.js is fetched and parsed for dependencies, how to deal with it later to let it show up in dom as script element without another http fetch. when we add script element to dom, there is always a http fetch(no cache enabled case), isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Your main.js script actually does get loaded as a `<script>` tag and run first; it's just that the function inside of it will not run until `a` and `b` are loaded. You do not need to add any script tags yourself if you are using requirejs.

To ensure `a`'s content function runs before `b`'s, simply define `a` as a dependency inside of `b`

```
// b.js
define(['a'], function(a) {
  // use a for initiation here
}
```

If you add `'c'` to that array, then `c` will also become an indirect dependency of `main.js`.

EDIT: In response to comment, this might give a better understanding. Each numbered item is one single HTTP request.

1. HTML retrieved
2. Requirejs itself is the first script seen, so that is loaded first.
3. Requirejs sees that its tag has a `data-main` attribute, and so retrieves `main.js` as a `<script>` tag. Once main.js has loaded, it would simply run the function on the inside of it, BUT, it looks like this file has dependencies (the array) that have not been loaded yet. SO, it creates `<script>` tags simultaneously for...
4. `a.js`
5. and `b.js`. Now, let's say this one finishes loading first - maybe `a.js` is really big. BUT! It looks like b has a dependency - on A. So, it won't run the inside function just yet. Requirejs knows that it's already waiting for `a.js`'s script tag, so it won't send out a separate request for it - it can just wait on it. Once that loads, a's function runs, then b's, then main's.

No HTTP requests are wasted here - Requirejs sends out requests as soon as it's aware of a dependency, and doesn't request individual scripts multiple times, except in rare occasions when it has no way of knowing that something is going to be loaded.

An example of this rare occasion might be if `SmallWidget.js` is an individual dependency, compiled into a large file called `BundleOfWidgets.js`. (For a final build, many scripts are often wrapped into one) If one script requests `BundleOfWidgets.js` but then another script requests `SmallWidget.js` before that arrives, it won't know it's actually loading `SmallWidget.js` in a big package, and so it will retrieve that individual file on its own.

Comment: i totally understand what  you were saying, but the i would like to know how requirejs implements this feature inside. how to run the script first and lastly add the main.js file in the header without another http fetch.

Comment: @user2009854 Okay, added some more detail. I don't agree with what you're saying about an extra HTTP fetch; if you can show me a list of script requests in your browser's Network tab, I could identify if or why that's needed.